# Upgrade Azure Corda deployment to latest 3.1 version

Tags: azure, upgrade, corda

We have an Azure based deployment of 'Corda Single ledger N/w' for Corda version 1.0

Azure seems to support deployment only Corda 1.0/2.0 max.

We need to upgrade it to the latest 3.1

Do we have a manual way for doing this please?

Comment: What are you looking to upgrade exactly? Are you looking to individually upgrade the nodes on your Azure machine? Or are you looking for an upgraded template to automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

[Image of parameters.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEYzM.png)

If you're looking for getting your VMs deployed with the 3.1 version just download the template from azure, open the parameters.json and specify cordaVersion as seen in maven central, so it would be "3.1-corda".